# How do I get my data from a soon-to-be-closed beta site if I am not a programmer?

Tags: support, data-dump, stackexchange-2.0

The Economics beta was given [a 9-day eviction notice](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159/economics-is-closing) (how typical for SE).

It mentions a link to [a blog post about data dumps](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/creative-commons-data-dump-sep-11/) but the [latest Clear Bits data dump](http://www.clearbits.net/creators/146-stack-exchange-data-dump/contents/page/1) is for December 2011 and does not contain beta sites.

**Question 1: How do I get my data from Economics beta?**

**Question 2: How do I get my data in readable format? (not XML)**

Comment: The XML format is pretty lame. I tried to peek at Atheism's data the other day and it's sort of a nightmare

Answer (score 3):

As stated on [the Stack Exchange blog entry of April 25th](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/04/when-a-site-grows-quiet/):

> all content on closed sites will be available for download from the Area 51 page corresponding to each site, in the same format and with the same open license as the data dumps for graduated sites.

I imagine this will occur after the site is actually closed.

After the data is released, others may come along and package it or provide tools to deal with the XML.  You could certainly ask for help with that on the appropriate SE site, too.

---

However, in your case (and maybe several others) you can easily grab your contributions to the site with a few mouse clicks.

[You've only got 3 questions, 1 answer and 12 comments](https://economics.stackexchange.com/users/77/daniel-sedlacek).  Plus, The answer is to your own question and the comments are all on your own questions.

Visit these 3 pages and save them from your browser.  You will then have your entire contribution to that site (not counting your 20 votes in 6 months) in a handy HTML format:

- [Question 1](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1210/examples-of-gold-inflation-and-deflation)
- [Question 2](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1216/will-insufficient-money-supply-slow-down-economic-growth)
- [Question 3](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1237/real-wages-vs-economic-growth)

If your comments *weren't* already included in the question pages, you could grab them by [filtering your activity page](https://economics.stackexchange.com/users/77/daniel-sedlacek?tab=activity&sort=comments).

Comment: Thanks for the link, it would be useful to copy i to the closing notice (not everyone is reading all SE blogposts). And thanks for the friendly attitude [sarcasm].

Comment: Yeah, okay.  I read your other posts and got a little snarky.  Toned it down a bit.

Comment: You are welcome. And once again thanks for the answer. In my case it's obviously easy but also want to keep other questions for their resources. (Speaking of which I AM a programmer and I can handle XML dumps, I was asking on behalf of my colleague and other users.)